# Microsoft.Graph SDK Search members of a group["x"] startwith 'A"

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to replicate this OData cast into my DOTNET core project:

I am using Microsoft.Graph (4.2.0) nuget package

This is my OData cast that works fine in Graph Explorer. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'A')

This is my code:

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>();
queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));

var groupMembers = await graphClient.Groups[$"{groupId}"].Members
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                //.Filter("startswith(displayName, 'E')")
                //.Search("displayName:Eric")
                .GetAsync();
```

When I try to run with:

> .Filter("startswith(displayName, 'E')")

I receive the error:

> Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery Message: The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported

I cannot use .Search because
'IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesRequest' does not contain a definiton for Search

Comment: Could you add this code and check how the uri inside http request looks like and how it differs from your original request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'A')? var httpRequestMessage = graphClient.Groups[$"{groupId}"].Members.Request(queryOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual").Filter("startswith(displayName, 'A')").GetHttpRequestMessage();

Comment: Hi this what I get from httpRequestMessage variable, there is no difference from my OData. `{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith%28displayName%2C %27D%27%29', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:{  ConsistencyLevel: eventual}}`

Comment: I am trying to use Microsoft.Graph SDK instead RestSharp to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```cs
string userGroupNameFilter = $"startswith(displayName,'CT-')";
List<Option> graphRequestOptions = new List<Option>() {
                                                        new QueryOption("$count", "true")
                                                      //,new QueryOption("$filter", userGroupNameFilter)
                                                      //,new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                                                       };
var userGroups = await graphClient.Users[$"{user.Id}"].TransitiveMemberOf
                                  .Request(graphRequestOptions)
                                  // .Header("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=100")
                                  .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                                  //.Header("Count", "true")
                                  .Filter(userGroupNameFilter)
                                  .GetAsync();
```